# Vue js 3. Not rendering any data variables value while using {{ someVariable }} syntax

Tags: vuejs3

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sorting Words</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app">
        <h1>Sorting Words</h1>
        <div>
            <label for="words">Enter words (comma-separated):</label>
            <input type="text" id="words" v-model="inputWords">
        </div>
        {{ inputWords }}
    </div>

    <script>
        const app = Vue.createApp({
            data() {
                return {
                    inputWords: ''
                };
            }
        });

        app.mount('#app');
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

The above code is working **absolutely fine** in https://playcode.io/vue but not working when I host it on my local machine and check in a web browser.

It just doesn't show any data for {{ inputWords }}

I checked the Vue Devtools and it's showing the data over there properly also, just not rendering it on the screen.. I tried other variables also but same problem.

Tried it on Chrome, Edge and Brave. Same behaviour across the board !

[Console Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bBgu.png)
[Vue DevTools Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPHPo.png)

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is maybe that you are using the default vue build in a "normal" html page.
Vue syntax is not real javascript, it needs to be transpiled in javascript to correctly be understand by the browser.
And the default build don't do that for you automatically

I assume it is working in playcode cause the platform transpile the code for you on the fly.

The Vue team also provide a global build intended for this usage, try to replace :

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>`
```

with this one

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.js"></script>
```

for more informations you can check the quick start page of Vue : https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#using-vue-from-cdn

Comment: Nope.. Same behaviour.. No errors but no rendering either !

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you're encountering an issue with your **Vue.js** code not rendering as expected on your local machine. Based on my experience, I was able to successfully run the exact same code on **JsFiddle** without any problems.

```
JsFiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/4319e0m5/1/
```

This suggests that the code itself is likely correct, and the issue might be related to the local environment or configuration. Here are a few things you might consider checking:

**File Paths and Project Structure:** Ensure that the file paths to the **Vue.js** library and other resources are correctly set up.

**Local Server:** **Vue.js** applications often require a local server to be properly served. You might want to use a local development server like Vue CLI or http-server to serve your files.

**Browser Compatibility:** Make sure that you are using a modern browser that is compatible with **Vue.js**. If you are using an older browser, it might not render the Vue components correctly.

**Check Browser Console:** Open your browser's developer console (usually by pressing F12 or right-clicking and selecting "Inspect") to check if there are any error messages or warnings that could provide insights into what's going wrong.

**JavaScript Enabled:** Verify that JavaScript is enabled in your browser settings, as **Vue.js** relies heavily on JavaScript for its functionality.

**Network Issues:** Ensure you have a stable internet connection, as some resources might fail to load if your connection is unreliable.

If you're still facing issues, it might be helpful to share any error messages you're encountering in the browser console, as they could offer more clues about the problem.

Additionally, you can compare the behavior you're seeing on your local machine with the working example on **JsFiddle** to identify any differences in environment or setup. I hope this information helps you troubleshoot and resolve the issue.

Comment: Nope. No browser errors or anything at all. Have updated question with Screenshots and Tried on multiple browsers.